# Can not echo array values

Tags: php, arrays

In this code:

```
<?php
$a=1;
$b=2;
echo "$a $b";
?>
```

It outputs `1 2`. But when I use for array:

```
<?php
echo "$good_data['first_name'] $good_data['last_name'] ";
?>
```

An error appears:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\my_application\formprocess.php on line 129

I have tried:

```
echo "$good_data['first_name']". "$good_data['last_name'] ";
```

But it doesn't work too!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another way, use { }

```
echo "{$good_data['first_name']} {$good_data['last_name']} ";
```

Answer (score 3):

You should not use string interpolation (i.e. a variable contained in a `"`-delimited string).

You should instead use string concatenation:

```
<?php
echo $good_data['first_name'] . " " . $good_data['last_name'];
```

Comment: An example of this method (and string interpolation method): http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/sqe-k34

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
<?php
     echo $good_data['first_name']." ".$good_data['last_name']." ";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are echoing an array you must put brackets when you use it between double quotes.

```
$a = array(1, 2);

echo "{$a[0]} {$a[1]}"; // Output : 1 2
```

Answer (score 0):

When interpolating array items you need to enclose them in `{...}`, like so:

```
echo "{$good_data['first_name']} {$good_data['last_name']}";
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
<?php
echo $good_data['first_name'].$good_data['last_name'];
?>
```